# Can't get all document from collection firebase firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I don't understand why I can't get data from firebase firestore database.

my error :

> [FirebaseError: Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore]

My config file with firebase config is correctly set, I can add Data with this model :

```
{ item: { ...event, date } }
```

My files structures : [picture of my structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiIKg.png)

I have correctly declared my state, I have async await with try catch.

I have used this from firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection)

EventList.js

```
import { FlatList, View, Text, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { EVENTS_COLLECTION } from "../commons/constants";
import db from "../commons/services/firebase";

const EventList = () => {
  const [events, setEvents] = useState([]);



  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList
        data={events}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <View style={styles.eventContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.eventName}>{item.name}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.eventDate}>{item.date.toString()}</Text>
          </View>
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

firebase.Js

```
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  databaseURL:
    "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "",
  measurementId: "",
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const db = getFirestore(app);
```

I try to get all documents from my events collection.
My goal is to make an Calendar with event manager with firebase firestore database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In firebase.js you export db like this:

```js
export const db = getFirestore(app);
```

This is a named export, therefore you will need a named import:

```js
import { db } from '../commons/services/firebase'
// or
// import * as config from '../commons/services/firebase'
// const db = config.db
```

The way you import is for default exports and results in your case with `undefined`. Therefore firebase complains that the first argument to `collection` is not correct (it's undefined).

You can read more about imports [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one if EVENTS_COLLECTION returns the name of the collection correctly then you will get all documents otherwise use `"Collection Name"` where you write EVENTS_COLLECTION.

```
const fetchEvents= async () => { 
     await db.collection(EVENTS_COLLECTION).onSnapshot({
          error: e => console.error(e),
          next: (querySnapshot) => {
               var data = [];
               var i = 0;
               querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
                    data.push(doc.data());
                    console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
               });
               setEvents(data)
          },
     })   
};
```